# How can I push a new branch to remote with only one commit in history?

Tags: git

I want my **commit history to remain as clean as possible** when pushing to remote branch. I would like to push only one commit that sums up all the commits I've done locally.

I have tried squashing but it didn't really work for me, or I'm doing it wrong.

What I do know is that I **soft reset** `git reset --soft HEAD~1` my local commits and then I create a new commit which is the one I actually push.7

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Squashing sounds like the right tool. What didn't work? Please may you share the commands and their outputs?

Comment: You can only push commits that exist in your repository. If you wish to have some particular commit, you must make that commit. Squashing (soft-reset-and-committing) is a good way to make that one commit. The only thing that seems to be missing from your own summary is why you chose `HEAD~1` as the commit to reset *to*. If you're trying to replace several commits that you have not yet merged, that may be the wrong target.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your reply. I soft reset, as I do not want to lose the changes but simply uncommit the multiple commits I've made locally as a safety net, before pushing to remote. So I reset all local commits when I'm happy with my changes, and then sum them up to a single commit, then push to remote. I have tried squashing but it always messes up the head of my commit, it hasn't been practical for me so far. I'm wondering if I can script my own git commands so I automate my procedure.

Comment: Squashing is an automated procedure. What do you mean by "messes up the head"?

Comment: If you've made, say, 5 commits in a nice neat linear row, and wish to squash those five to make a single commit, you'd want `git reset --soft HEAD~5` followed by `git commit`. That is, the number of first-commit steps you want to move backwards is exactly the same as the number of commits you made (since each one was the first and only child of the corresponding parent).